# Can anybody explain what is going on here in terms of type coercion, IIFE, and closures?

Tags: javascript, closures, iife

can anyone explain to me what is JS doing here? Can anybody explain what is going on here in terms of type coercion, IIFE, and closures?

```
Function.prototype.toString = (
    function() {
      const toStringFnRef = Function.prototype.toString;
      
      return function() {
            return `start:${toStringFnRef.call(this)}end`;
        }
    }
)();

console.log(1 + function x() { alert('hi') });
//output: "1start:function x() { alert('hi') }end"
```

Comment: Are you asking because this is code you want to avoid in future because it's terrible?

Comment: The type coercion is explained in the [specification](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-applystringornumericbinaryoperator), as is [`Function.prototype.toString`](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function.prototype.tostring). `call` is explained in the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), closures are explained here: [How do JavaScript closures work?](/q/111102/4642212). Please see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/4642212). What, specifically, is unclear?

Comment: Related: [How to override Function.prototype.toString](/q/26697520/4642212)

Comment: @Andy Question that came up in an interview

Comment: And my answer to that question would be "I wouldn't touch that code with a barge-pole. Is this code indicative of the code I would be expected to engage with?" There are much nicer ways of trying to get interviewees to explain closures and IIFEs.

Comment: @Andy Haha I wish I could say that, but this is company that I really wanted

Comment: Yeah, maybe that was a bit harsh, but I've been in the game for a long time and done a lot of ridiculous interviews. My question to them would be why they think it's appropriate to add a new method to the function prototype, and what they hope to achieve. As you get older sometimes you have to say "this is just bad code". But I wish you well for your job hunt. @ehehe341

Answer (score 0):

The IIFE is being used to create a local scope where the variable `toStringFnRef` contains the original value of `Function.prototype.toString`. Then it redefines this with a function that calls the original function and wraps the result in `start:` and `end`.

This could also be done using a lexical block (in ES6 most IIFEs can be refactored like this):

```
{
  const toStringFnRef = Function.prototype.toString;

  Function.prototype.toString = function() {
    return `start:${toStringFnRef.call(this)}end`;
  }
}
```

When you do `1 + function x() { alert('hi') }` it converts both `1` and the function to strings so it can concatenate them. So this calls your redefined `Function.prototype.toString()`, which surrounds the normal string of the function with those wrappers. This is then concatenated with `1`.

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but how is the function definition: alert('hi') being outputted, would "this" represent function x() { alert('hi')?

Comment: `this` in a prototype function is the object it's being called on. So if you have `f = function() { ...}` and you do `f.toString()`, `this` will be the value of `f`.

Comment: @ehehe341 See [How does the "this" keyword work?](/q/3127429/4642212) and [the specification](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toprimitive). Note that ToPrimitive with argument `input` implicitly invokes (among other things) the equivalent of `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object(input)).toString.call(input)` which boils down to `input.toString()`; `input` is the function, in this case.

Comment: So why do we have to return a function() instead of just returning: return `start:${toStringFnRef.call(this)}end`; ?

Comment: Because the value of `Function.prototype.toString` has to be a function.

Comment: Isn't the return value of Function.prototype.toString a string though?

Comment: @Barmar By value, do you mean the return value?

Comment: You get the string when you call `toString()`. You need to assign a function to `toString()` so you can call it later.